# Inherited Widget Throws Null Error , when trying to get values from child wdget

Tags: flutter, dart

I created Inherited widget for passing a value of a Custom Class , wrapped the the inherited widget on MyHomePage widget then tried to access the value in the child widget using .of method but getting null error even i passed the value in top of the widget tree.

```
    class PersonInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
    final PersonModel person;

     const PersonInheritedWidget({
      required this.person,
      required Widget child,
      }) : super(child: child);

      static PersonInheritedWidget? of(BuildContext context) {
       return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<PersonInheritedWidget>();
       }

      @override
       bool updateShouldNotify(PersonInheritedWidget oldWidget) {
      return person != oldWidget.person;
         }
        }
```

---

```
       home: PersonInheritedWidget(
      person: PersonModel(name: 'John Doe', age: 25),
    child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
     ),
```

---

```
      final person = PersonInheritedWidget.of(context)?.person;
       print(person);

       console : null
```

Comment: the code is working fine for me

Comment: can you plz share your code

Comment: same code bro, you update it with your full code